# How pass a value to a variable in python function with using exec()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A little easy problem:

```
exec("a=3")
print(a)

# This will print 3
```

If I use this:

```
def func():
    exec("a=3")
    print(a)

func()

# NameError: name 'a' is not defined.
```

What happened?How could I use `exec()` to assign it a value in a function?

Edit:I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774217/exec-function-in-a-function-is-not-workingpython-3-5) with the same trouble but still didn't solved.

> why do you want to do that?

I know using `exec()` is bad and unsafe.But recently I try to solve a OP's problem.I met it.

Comment: The real question seems to be: why do you want to do that?

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168282/setting-variables-with-exec-inside-a-function?

Comment: @schwobaseggl So `exec()` couldn't be use to `local variable`?

Comment: yep, this is definitely a dup to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168282/

Comment: Why are you using `exec` at all? It is *not* something you need ordinarily.

Comment: "But recently I try to solve a OP's problem" - whatever their problem was, it almost certainly shouldn't be approached with `exec` either.

Comment: Hmmm,I know that.But now I want to know whether it could do that and why this will happen.Even if I didn't use it.

Comment: Do you want to know *what happened* (i.e. why this doesn't work) or *how to do it* anyways?

Comment: ``why this doesn't work``.That's what I mean.I won't use `exec()` or `eval()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python knows several kinds of scope: [module `global`, function local, `nonlocal` closures, class body](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names). Notably, scope resolution is defined [statically at byte code compile time](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/) – most importantly, whether names refer to local/nonlocal or global scope cannot be changed.

Of these scopes, only global scope is guaranteed to behave similar to a `dict`, and as such writeable. The local/nonlocal scope is generally not writeable, and new variables cannot be added to it.

`exec` will write to the global scope if *locals* is not passed in; *globals* must then explicitly be set to its default of `globals()`.

```
def func():
    exec("a='exec'", globals())  # access only global scope
    print(a)

a = 'global'
func()  # prints exec
```

However, once a name is local to a function, `exec` cannot modify it.

```
def func():
    a = 'local'  # assignment makes name local
    exec("a='exec global'", globals())
    exec("a='exec locals'", globals(), locals())
    print(a)

a = 'global'
func()  # prints local
```

---

While a `dict`-like representation of local/nonlocal scope exists, the interpreter is not required to honour changes to it.

> #### [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)
>
> Update and return a dictionary representing the current local symbol table. Free variables are returned by locals() when it is called in function blocks, but not in class blocks. Note that at the module level, locals() and globals() are the same dictionary.
>
> > Note: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; **changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.**

Even though `exec` does take locals as a `dict`, these are not treated like function locals/nonlocals. Attempts to modify the default locals (the result of `locals()`) are not defined.

> #### [exec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)
>
> ... If globals and locals are given, they are used for the global and local variables, respectively. If provided, locals can be any mapping object. Remember that at module level, globals and locals are the same dictionary. **If exec gets two separate objects as globals and locals, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition.**
>
> > Note: The default *locals* act as described for function `locals()` below: **modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be attempted.** ...

Comment: I think you maybe misunderstand me.Maybe you can tell me what's the principle of `exec()`(like how does it work.).In the second example of my code,All of them have no connection with the `global` or `nonlocal` and so on(it is just local variable in the function.So `exec()` execute this python code.Why couldn't print it?).Whatever,thanks for your work.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I've added two examples of how your code makes variables global or local, and how this affects the behaviour of ``exec``.

Answer (score 2):

execute `help(exec)` in your python3 REPL, you will get the following docuement:

```
Help on built-in function exec in module builtins:

exec(source, globals=None, locals=None, /)
    Execute the given source in the context of globals and locals.

    The source may be a string representing one or more Python statements
    or a code object as returned by compile().
    The globals must be a dictionary and locals can be any mapping,
    defaulting to the current globals and locals.
    If only globals is given, locals defaults to it.
```

so there are at least 2 options to provide the value of argument 'a':

1. assign a value to the variable 'a' in the module's global scope:

```
a = 1

def func():
    exec("global a;a=3")
    print(a)
```

2. pass a customized global or local context to exec:

```
def func():
    my_context = {'a': 1}
    exec("a=3", None, my_context)
    print(my_context['a'])
```

NOTE: DONT USE `eval` or `exec` IN YOUR SERIOUS CODE UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING.

---

### EDIT NOTE

the following solution(2th solution mentioned in the comments) wont work:

```
def func():
   a = 1
   exec("a=3")
   print(a) # still get 1 here
```

Comment: Assigning locals in `exec` is undefined behavior. The usual result is that [it looks like nothing even happens](https://ideone.com/P9mwI7).

Comment: Well.The 2th example doesn't work.But others is right.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks for pointing out, the second solution does not work, and thanks for sharing the tool  ideone.com